# The specified child already has a parent. Console says must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewholder, android-viewgroup

I see all questions and answers about this error but I can't solve this.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.rel_pie_l=(RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rel_pie_l); 
            v.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        } 
        holder.rel_pie_l.removeAllViews();

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.rel_pie_l.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = mItems.get(i).rel_size;
        holder.rel_pie_l.setLayoutParams(params); 
        holder.rel_pie_l.addView(mItems.get(i).rel_pie_l);


        return v;
    }
```

Error appears when the keyboard is active on the listview and when the keyboard is gone then error appears on **addview** line

How can I solve this? I use remove view .

Answer (score 0):

Remove this -

```
    holder.rel_pie_l.removeAllViews();
```

And change the last part of your code like this -

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = 
     holder.rel_pie_l.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = mItems.get(i).rel_size;
    holder.rel_pie_l.setLayoutParams(params); 
    if(holder.rel_pie_l.getParent() != null) { 
   ((ViewGroup)holder.rel_pie_l.getParent()).removeView(holder.rel_pie_l); 
    }
    holder.rel_pie_l.addView(mItems.get(i).rel_pie_l);
```

Comment: when I do not use this line it do not error:holder.rel_pie_l.addView(mItems.get(i).rel_pie_l);

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that your view `mItems.get(i).rel_pie_l` already has a parent layout which is defined in your `xx.xml` file, so you cannot add that view to another view. 
Also, you don't need to remove views and re-add them in order for `setLayoutParams` to work. Just set them directly, and remove `removeAllViews` and `addView`